# Как скрыть первый встречающийся селектор не изменяя html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет. Мне нужно скрыть первый встречающийся `param-count`, но ни с помощью способа 1, ни способа 2 не выходит. Как можно это сделать не изменяя структуру html и желательно с помощью стилей?

```html
<div class="archive">
  <div class="shop-page-meta">
    <!--много div-->
    <div class="param-count">
      Содержимое 1
    </div>
    <!--/ .param-count-->
    <!--много div-->
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-holder">Текст 1</div>
  <div class="woof_products_top_panel">Текст 2</div>
  <ul class="products clearfix">Текст 3</div>
<div class="shop-page-meta">
  <!--много div-->
  <div class="param-count">
    Содержимое 1
  </div>
  <!--/ .param-count-->
  <!--много div-->
</div>
...
</div>
```

Способ 1:
`.archive:first-child .param-count {
  display: none;

}`
Способ 2:
`.archive .param-count:first-child {
  display: none;

}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вполне работает: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ynzpw2j1/

Фича в том, что если перед ним есть еще что-то, другой левый блок, то не сработает:
http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ynzpw2j1/1/

```
<div class="archive">
    <div></div>
    <div class="param-count">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div class="param-count">Содержимое 2</div>
</div>
```

Но даже в этой ситуации скрыть все равно можно:
http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ynzpw2j1/2/

```
.param-count {
    display: none;
}
.param-count + .param-count {
    display: block;
}
```

UPD:
В случае очень очень сложной структуры и невозможности изменить html, можно так же очень легко скрыть на js:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.param-count');
items[0].style.display = 'none';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ynzpw2j1/6/

Comment: да, есть и притом много. один блок расположен вверху страницы, а второй в самом низу

Comment: Я так и понял, используйте последний совет.

Comment: Можно вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ynzpw2j1/3/

Comment: Спасибо. последний вариант только помог